# Control free and fixed static margin

Tags: aerodynamics

For many aircraft root and tip chord is given but the exact location of aerodynamic center and center of gravity is not given. Considering this information;
How can I calculate control free and fixed static margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stick-free static margin depends a lot on the elevator hinge moment coefficients of the aircraft. Depending on the sign of the hinge moment derivative with angle of attack ($c_{r_\alpha}$), the stick-free stability can be **greater** than the stick-fixed stability (greater for positive $c_{r_\alpha}$ because then the control surface will deflect into the changed airstream). By how much depends also on the derivative over deflection angle $c_{r_\eta}$, but this one should definitely stay in the negative range, or the stick will be hard to center.

The stick-fixed margin is much easier to calculate. If aspect ratio is reasonably high, the surface-weighted mean of the quarter points of all horizontal surfaces will give a good approximation of the neutral point $x_N$, and the center of gravity depends on the loading of the aircraft. Normally, you would calculate the margin for both the most forward and the most backward cg location $x_S$ for which the aircraft is certified.

With the given planform, the mean aerodynamic chord $l_\mu$ is also easy to calculate, and the stick-fixed margin is (x backwards positive): $$\frac{c_{M\alpha}}{c_{L\alpha}} = \frac{(x_S - x_N)}{l_\mu}$$

Answer (score 0):

CG is never given as a fixed location because it changes with loading of the aircraft and other parameters. The control free neutral point is the CG location at which the control free pitch stiffness vanishes. That means that the control free point moves when the CG changes. The fixed static margin can be stick-free or stick-neutral and changes with CG, but also with elevator area.